# What is the purpose of the [pokemon] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, pokemon

On most Pokemon questions people add the [pokemon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon) tag, but it's often removed in the first edit by other users.

So my question is: is it wrong to use that tag for a question about a specific game? If so, what's its purpose?

Comment: I merged [tag:pokemon] into [tag:pokemon-series]. This disambiguates the usage. I will try to go over questions with that tag over the next little while and clean it up, as well. Feel free to pitch in.

Comment: Thanks, now it's definitely clearer.