# What tags should I use to ask about the Madden series as a whole?

Tags: support, tags

I have a question about the entire Madden series. How do I get this across in the tags? Do I have to use every Madden tag?

Comment: See also: [When should the \[*-series\] tags be created?](//gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14671/28182)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ask about the series as a whole, it’s recommended to use a tag that indicates it as such. In this case, it would be [madden-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/madden-series). We have multiple tags like this, such as [final-fantasy-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-series) and [pokemon-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-series)

Since you have over 300 rep, you can create the tag if it does not already exist.

Comment: I didn't see "madden-series" suggested when I typed "Madden" in the tags field.  Thank you.

Comment: Why do we use the tags "madden-series", "pokemon-series", etc instead of the shorter and simpler tags "madden", "pokemon", etc.

Comment: @OlaStröm We do it like that when there are multiple games in a series because  games like `final-fantasy`, `half-life`, `kingdom-hearts`, `portal`, and many others would cause overlap with an individual game vs the series

Comment: @OlaStröm We also get a lot of people who wouldn't understand what the tag is for. [pokemon-series] WAS just [pokemon] for a lot of years, users would misunderstand it's purpose and add that tag to every question about Pokemon ([which would then get removed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10219/28182), leaving them confused)